# Run an application at each system boot in Arch Linux

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, cron, startup, application

I am using Arch Linux. I don't have any special permissions, I am just user without any special privileges.
I want to start an application after each boot.

I have already tried using crontab jobs, using @reboot . But it's not working.

How to run application at every system boot, (solutions for execution after login is even better).

Additional information: I have tried adding same cron job (using @reboot) job in Ubuntu also, but its also not working.

My crontab job:

```
@reboot /home/username/get_stats.py
```

**Command should execute after first login after each reboot**.

Comment: It's not working.... what is not working, why don't you show us your @reboot line by editing your question. Login can happen any number of times after reboot. Do you want something to happen on first login after reboot only, on every login?

Comment: Why are you down voting my question Mr. Anthon van der Neut  ?????????????

Comment: If you hover above the down arrow, you can see the reasons for downvoting. Why do you think I am downvoting this? (And if I could only do that once).

Comment: Is your get_stats.py executable? (output of `ls -l /home/username/get_stats.py`)

Comment: Yes, it is executable. -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: @reboot only works on Vixie cron IIRC. Do you have that installed? (`man cron` should be able to tell you). If you do have the `@reboot` only touch a file, then check in `get_stats.py` if the file exists -> exit if not, delete if it does and continue with the rest of script.

Comment: Note: I have also added command pidgin. i.e. @reboot /usr/bin/pidgin. That is also not working.

Comment: Are there any other methods to start an application at reboot or at login ?

Comment: to start application after login, you might wish to edit .bash_profile (in command line). windows manager allow application to be launch upon windows manager run.

Comment: I have already tried editing .bash_profile in text editor, How to edit .bash_profile in command line ? Is it possible without any special privileges ? How to run application using windows manager ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line to your .bashrc file, so that it will be executed after restart and first login:
echo "python /home/username/myscript.py" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: This will execute on each and every login after a reboot, not just the first login and that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Whether i should add the line in .bashrc or .bash_profile ?